# Does ETag invalidate the Cache-Control header?

Tags: caching, http-headers, etag, http-status-code-304, if-none-match

I am fetching a resource from my RESTful web service, and in the response I add these two headers:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=120
ETag: "3D03F8066015A1438532E049AE5E16EA"
```

The first time the browser got this response it cached it correctly for 2 minutes.

However, the next time I requested the resource, my browser now sent an `IfNoneMatch` header, and got a `304 Not Modified` as expected, along with another `Cache-Control` header to cache for 2 minutes.

**BUT** the browser did not cache the response. I keep refreshing the page, and it keeps making the request, and therefore keeps getting `304 Not Modified`.

Is this a normal behavior?

How do I tell the browser to revalidate its cached resource for 2 more minutes, after it gets a `304 Not Modified`, and to not make any more requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should HTTP 304 Not Modified-responses contain cache-control headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587667/should-http-304-not-modified-responses-contain-cache-control-headers)

Comment: Read over the question @Joe linked.  What you describe sounds like the correct behavior.  When you say "the browser did not cache the response" ... how do you know this?  A 304 indicates that it DID cache it.  Also, if you refresh over and over for longer than 2 minutes and it is still getting a 304, then the browser applied the 'new' TTL from the 304 responses.

Comment: The browser provides the `ETag` of the cached asset in the browser on the `If-None-Match` HTTP request header, then the server checks the token against current assets in the cache. If the `Etag` and `If-None-Match` headers match the `304 Not Modified` response is sent to the browser. This process ocurrs every 120 seconds based on the `max-age`.